# PHP preg replace to change last two character in whole string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem in preg_replace.

I have a text file which includes:

```
#define FWTE_BLACK "{000000FF
#define FWTE_TEST "{006600FF
...
```

The complete text is here : https://eval.in/133942

I would like to replace the ending `FF` on each line to `}"`
Like this :

```
#define FWTE_BLACK "{000000}"
#define FWTE_TEST "{006600}"
...
```

Comment: can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: "*I want to replace ending FF on each line to }*" — What is that supposed to mean? I'm not sure what is it that you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to replace all lines ending with `FF` to `FF}`?

Comment: @iFarbod check my answer help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
preg_replace('/(.*)[F]{2}$/','$1}"','#define FWTE_BLACK "{000000FF');
```

*Based on your comment this is the update:*

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*)[F]{2}([\n\r])+/','$1}"$2',$myString);
```

http://ideone.com/UOsenT

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
preg_replace('/FF$/m', '}"', $file_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#FF$#', '}"' $content);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Pattern (Here I **[check](http://www.regexr.com/38m53)**)

```
/\w{2}$/
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ji4CQG)**</kbd>

#### PHP

```
<?php   
    $str = "#define FWTE_TEST \"{006600FF";
    $pattern = '/\w{2}$/';
    $replacement = '}"';  

    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
?>
```

#### Result

```
#define FWTE_TEST "{006600}"
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: my text is just not one #define FWTE_TEST \"{006600FF

Comment: alline are same so whats all string demo you want to show you?

Comment: PHP no need to write /g end of regexp. so i a not write but you can see pattern link /g is have. So basically if get help from here your responsibility to give vote credential for spending time for you.

Comment: check this what is stackoverflow why vote is helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: check your rep 15+ now you able to do this.